# Uib-popover should show limited characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an uib-popover which is currently showing 4000 characters. How can I display 100 characters only(like textoverflow property) in that popover?
Please find the screenshot attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb3aE.png) as well.

here is my html code:

```
 <i class="{{::prefix}}_TableCol_PrescriptionList_Notes_Text_OfficeComments fa fa-comment"
                   ng-show="prescription.officeNotes && showComments" uib-popover="Office Comments: {{ prescription.officeNotes }}" popover-placement="top"
                   popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-animation="0"
                   ng-click="!prescription.disabledDueToSPM && showIconData(prescription, $event, 'officeNotes')"></i>
```

Here is my css file code:

```
    .popover.top {
  margin-top: -5px !important;
  font-size: 9pt;
  max-width: 500px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the attribute on your HTML tag, use [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo):

```
uib-popover="Office Comments: {{ prescription.officeNotes | limitTo : 100 }}"
```

Comment: Good to hear! Have an upvote for accepting the answer to a good question.